# Magento 1.9.1.0 product images are not showing after migrating

Tags: php, magento, dns, migrate

I've migrated my magento website from demo to live server, imported database, same files and everything from demo version, and changed url's in database, but for some reason products images which have been working on demo site are not showing up on live.

Now, i've tried:

1. Delete /var/cache, /var/sessions
2. Delete /media/cache
3. Move /media/catalog/product to /media/import and import products through admin panel using csv
4. Import products using csv
5. Replace strings in database
6. [UPDATE]: Forgot to mention that i've tried to chmod /media and /var folders recursively with 777 rights
7. Also, i've tried removing .htaccess file from /media folder - didn't made any difference.

The interesting thing is that on demo website, when i open url like: http://mydemowebsite/magento_demo/media/catalog/product/i/m/img_1204_image_name_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1.jpg
i can see the image BUT when i go to /media/catalog/product/i/m/ i can't find img_1204... file anywhere. Crazy, huh... ?

and when i open the same url but with my live websites domain name - i have blank page.

[UPDATE]: I've tried editing get.php file, and it seems that when i try to access image through url on my live site, if i'll add echo "something" - the text will appear in the browser. 
If i edit get.php on my demo website - text doesn't appear at all. Even if i add die('something') at the beginning of the file.

Can anyone explain me what is happening and how can i fix this ? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: is ur test server & live server running on same kind of OS?

Comment: @Shan ,
Yes, everything is the same, as it's the same provider. The only difference is php version.
Live uses php 5.3.29, and demo 5.5.38

Comment: new product images are showing ? and what about images in admin, are you able to see them there?

Comment: Check for PHP has `gd` enabled on your server

Comment: @urfusion , yes, when i create a new product or jsut reupload image for old products - they appear just fine. And yes, GD is enabled

Comment: have you done reindexing

Comment: @urfusion Yes, didn't helped either

Comment: clear `log_` tables

Comment: Thanks for help everyone, but i found the problem. I've posted an answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem myself.
Thanks to everyone who tried to help, but the problem was:
FTP client shows only up to 10k images per folder. That folder had more than 10k files, and when i downloaded website files from demo server - i've downloaded only those 10k images per folder.
And that's why they didn't show up on live website